# Display row details as datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, detailview

I have a datagrid, which items are list of (just an example for easier understanding):

```
public class Person
{
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; }

  public List<Company> Companies { get; set; }
}

public class Company 
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string City { get; set; }
}
```

And now I want to display the companies in my RowDetailsTemplate.

I have tried to do this

```
<DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Companies}">
                [im trying to access the data of the row here]
            </DataGrid>
        </DataTemplate>
</DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
```

And my ItemsSource of the datagrid is a List (its readonly, its just to display, not edit data.)

My problem is, that I can't seem to access the Companies, but rather VS/R# only says that the `List<Person>` (with the name Persons inside of my viewModel) is available.

But I want to access the data per row, not every the data of all the rows. How do I do that?

Comment: So you want to access the detail (Companies) of the selected row?  Are you in MVVM?

Comment: Yes, and yes. I use prism, if that helps. Well rather, I plan to display all the details anyways, but thats a functionality RowDetailsTemplate provides anyways

Comment: _But I want to access the data of my row_ what you mean by _my row_ here?

Comment: you know, every row is represented by a ViewModel. this viewmodel has a list of companies. I want these companies in a datagrid in the detail view of the row. My row is not specific, it is the same for every row.

Comment: You are already doing that.  Each row is represented as `Person` and detail of the row will show the list of company of the respective row `Companies`.

Comment: Oh what - I just tested and realized it was working all along. This must be a bug of resharper and visual studio. The binding was marked as incorrect :o

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me explain you with an example.  Copy paste the following code and put the *breakpoint on `get` and `set` of `SelectedEmployee`*.

Now run the code and click the different row.  You will get the resepctive row item with list of details in it.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEmployee}" >
        <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Details}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    </DataGrid>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var detail1 = new EmployeeDetails() { ManagerID = 11, ManagerName = "11 Name", ManagerMobile = "123456" };
        var detail2 = new EmployeeDetails() { ManagerID = 12, ManagerName = "12 Name", ManagerMobile = "123456" };
        var detail3 = new EmployeeDetails() { ManagerID = 13, ManagerName = "13 Name", ManagerMobile = "123456" };

        var detail4 = new EmployeeDetails() { ManagerID = 11, ManagerName = "11 Name", ManagerMobile = "123456" };
        var detail5 = new EmployeeDetails() { ManagerID = 12, ManagerName = "12 Name", ManagerMobile = "123456" };
        var detail6 = new EmployeeDetails() { ManagerID = 13, ManagerName = "13 Name", ManagerMobile = "123456" };

        var detail7 = new EmployeeDetails() { ManagerID = 11, ManagerName = "11 Name", ManagerMobile = "123456" };
        var detail8 = new EmployeeDetails() { ManagerID = 12, ManagerName = "12 Name", ManagerMobile = "123456" };
        var detail9 = new EmployeeDetails() { ManagerID = 13, ManagerName = "13 Name", ManagerMobile = "123456" };

        var details1 = new List<EmployeeDetails>();
        details1.Add(detail1);
        details1.Add(detail2);
        details1.Add(detail3);

        var details2 = new List<EmployeeDetails>() { detail4, detail5, detail6 };
        var details3 = new List<EmployeeDetails>() { detail7, detail8, detail9 };

        Employees = new List<Employee>();
        Employees.Add(new Employee() { ID = 1, Name = "Name1", Details = details1 });
        Employees.Add(new Employee() { ID = 2, Name = "Name2", Details = details2 });
        Employees.Add(new Employee() { ID = 3, Name = "Name3", Details = details3 });            

        SelectedEmployee = Employees[1];

        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }

    private Employee _selected;

    public Employee SelectedEmployee
    {
        get { return _selected; }
        set { _selected = value; }
    }


}

public class Employee
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<EmployeeDetails> Details { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeDetails
{
    public int ManagerID { get; set; }
    public string ManagerName { get; set; }
    public string ManagerMobile { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Sometimes you just need someone to point out that you're dumb. However, if I didn't already had the correct approach, it would've solved my problem. Good answer!